# Creating Futures without ExecutorService or FutureTask

Tags: jax-rs, future, executorservice, jersey-client, futuretask

I am using JerseyClient to make async calls to a http server and am directly creating Futures to store the response. These can even be batch calls in which case I create a list of futures.

This is working perfectly for now but I am concerned about CPU Utilization and Thread Count as I am not creating any Thread Pool using Executor Service, nor am I using FutureTask<> to create futures.

Small Code snippet of how I am constructing each future:

```
Future<Response> response = requestBuilder.async().get();
```

Are these concerns valid? Is it okay to continue with this approach? Would this approach not scale?

Another concern is that a get() might never be performed on some of these futures? Would this lead to spawning threads that will never be killed because neither get() or cancel() is performed for the futures running on these threads?

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to control number of `threads` created by the application so while calling `REST API` using `Jersey async API`, you should limit number of `threads` created.

Below code can be used for controlling max number of `threads` created by `jersey client` in `async API` -

```
    ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig();
    cc.property(ClientProperties.ASYNC_THREADPOOL_SIZE  , 10);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
```

Another point related to `get()` method call on Future instance, `get()` method is just a blocking method which will make your `current thread` wait for completion of the `future task` in this case for the `response` to receive, it will not impact execution of `threads`. So, there should not be any issue if you are not calling `get()` or `cancel()` on response `Future` instance.